# Functional Test Tools for AWS IAM Policy Simulator

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, functional-testing, aws-codepipeline, aws-control-tower

This is my first post here, I am working on a AWS CodePipeline which creates new AWS Accounts and assign users through AWS SSO, which has Permissions Set with specific managed IAM policies and inline policy as permission boundary set for the user groups. I would like to use a test pipeline that tests the specific user role from the vended AWS account and test whether the user(s) able to perform certain actions such as enabling internet access, create policy etc and based on the results proceed further pipeline steps.

Example: The pipeline runs on POC environment creates an account, then will have to run the test against the SSO user / local IAM user to check if the user can create internet gateway etc, usually this can be an IAM policy simulator cli and it results whether the user action allowed or not. My pipeline flow should proceed moving the source to the "master" branch for the production environment depend on the test results or discard if fails.

I am trying few tools such as Taskcat and others most of them do not perform such functional test, only checks the existence of the resource.

Any suggestions for tools that can allow me to perform such functional test as part of the pipeline would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use "awspec" for achieving the functional test for the AWS resources, the one I was specifically looking for is of IAM policy simulator using the below "awspec" resource.

```
describe iam_role('my-iam-role') do
  it { should be_allowed_action('ec2:DescribeInstances') }
  it { should be_allowed_action('s3:Put*').resource_arn('arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*') }
end
```